# How to change config settings on local ios phonegap build from the new Phonegap CLI?

Tags: configuration, cordova, command-line-interface

**FYI**; Phonegap CLI: http://log.michaelbrooks.ca/post/phonegap-cli-preview

So, after making a build with the new Phonegap CLI, getting a project with the new Phonegap 3.0, I wanted to run my application on an ios simulator:

```
> phonegap local run ios
```

This successfully install the phonegap application onto the IOS 6.1 simulator and runs it- all good so far. Problem is that all REST-functionality is not working. I dig around and find out that the `phonegap local run ios` automatically creates a ios xcode project at `/platforms/ios/`. Inside this folder I can locate a config.xml-file with access origin set to only allow `http://127.0.0.1*`. Now, I want to change this, so I do. Problem is that when I run `phonegap local run ios` again the old config file is back.

So basically, the questions end out in:

**How do I change the Phonegap configuration settings when using Phonegap CLI?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I feel very embarrassed now, but I think its better to share then to delete :)

If you have a config.xml file in your www-folder (which shipped originally, but I have removed) you can change the values from there. This file will be copied over.

So in my config.xml-file inside my apps www-folder I found:

```
<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/>
```

Just before the last tag, . I changed this to:

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

And then everything worked :)